# Managing a thread from inside an Android Preference

Tags: android, android-preferences

This ought to have a simple answer, but I haven't yet figured out what it is.

I have a `Preference` subclass that spawns a new `Thread`, which needs to run for as long as the `Preference` is visible.  The `Thread` runs a `Looper` so I can signal it to quit using `Looper.quit()`.

The question is, where in the `Preference` class should I be calling `Looper.quit()`?

I've tried overriding `onPrepareForRemoval()`, but this function does not appear to be called.  I would prefer not to have to give my `PreferenceActivity` subclass special knowledge of this  `Preference`; I want the `Preference` to be self-contained.

Comment: What kind of preference is this? Why would it need a thread?

Comment: The kind that can be, and frequently is, changed from outside the preference activity, and needs to update its display.

Comment: Can't that be accomplished with a broadcastReceiver or preferenceChangeListener? These listeners are normally bound to the Activities context and will be destroyed when the activity is.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it is easier and cleaner to implement this using a broadcast or preferenceChangeListener.

Sending a broadcast is easy, just send in intent with a custom action. Register the receiver for that action in the preference and you'll be fine.

It is also decoupled from the rest of the code.

Comment: I have no control over outside changes.  There is no notification and so a polling thread is required.

Comment: You could spawn this thread from the activity and use broadcasts, that way you'll have lifecycle control and you do not need to register your preference in the activity

You could also let the activity implement an interface and cast the context to that specific type. This will allow you to bind to a specific interface. It only requires that the preference knows about the interface and the activity implementing it.

I think the first suggestion is cleaner, but I see no other simple solution

Comment: In neither case do I know when the preference is no longer being displayed, so I still don't know when to quit the thread.

Comment: you  can quit the thread on the onpause  in the preference activity. If this is no option I'm afraid I don't see another solution.